# how to limit the size of div to window dimensions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menubar(div) which houses bookmarks and when too many bookmarks are inserted this menu bar(div) becomes too wide for the preferred page size(1280, 720) and becomes scrollabe, leaving half of the bookmarks out of view.

[image]

I want to ensure that all the bookmarks are in view and the best option seems to be that I have to make the extra bookmarks appear on the next line. can someone guide me in the right direction or better yet provide a working sample. Im just learning to use jquery and am finding this very difficult.

[Example code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftaran/y9a64/8/)

Comment: This seems more like an HTML/CSS problem.  Have you tried making the container of the bookmarks in a div with 100% width? Also, make sure your HTML and BODY widths are 100%

Comment: Can you please show us the code for menubar(div)

Comment: code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ftaran/y9a64/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this in there on the `ul` element.

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Which means that that element's contents will never wrap to another line, so it extends out past the edge of the window instead.  Remove that rule, and you have something closer to what you want.  That is, when you content overflow one line, you want it to *wrap* to the next line.

http://jsfiddle.net/y9a64/9/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/bH8yA/
Are you looking for a solution like that? If so, it's straight CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using css  overflow-x: auto; please see example http://jsfiddle.net/Xa8yB/6/